# Finding Qt debug message source

Tags: qt, debugging

I have written an application with a big code base (around 30k lines) and sometimes, when it gets cpu intensive, the shell output is filled with something like this:

```
QPainter::scale: Painter not active
QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
QPainter::scale: Painter not active
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::translate: Painter not active
QPainter::scale: Painter not active
QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
QPainter::scale: Painter not active
```

which goes on forever. The problem is that I have tens of QPainter instances in many different widgets, so I can't trace it. Is there any way to trace these messages? I have encountered this problem many times in different projects. I have tried adding this to my project

```
QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN="[%{type}] %{appname} (%{file}:%{line}) - %{message}"
```

as suggested in Qt documentation, but after it I don't get any debug messages anymore. Totally stuck! Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just install a custom message handler, set a breakpoint into that, and wait for the errors to hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Where should I install it? I don't know!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add a link and it went away: see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler .

Comment: If you have the Qt debug libraries, you could just set a breakpoint in the `QPainter` function where the message is printed, and then examine the call stack

Comment: @peppe I couldn't reproduce the QPainter warning since testing your suggestion, but I think this is the way to go. If you submit it as an answer I would gladly accept it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution: Have a self-built debug version of Qt, then find these messages in its source, and set breakpoints there.

Most likely you're trying a widget outside its paint event, or from another thread. Or you're recursing event loops from within a paint event.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess peppe's answer is much easier to perform.

Comment: @Arash That will tell you where in your code the problem is, but won't tell you why Qt didn't like it as you won't see Qt's source. If you use the message system for logging, the message handler might be called thousands of times every second, so it'll be almost impossible to catch the message you're after merely by setting a breakpoint in the message handler. You'll have to add a regex to catch the message you're after, at the very least.